# The usual display of a 3D scene in the XCODE 12 does not work

Tags: xcode, scenekit, xcode12

After updating to version 12, in all scenes where there is a display of 3D objects, what is shown below is shown in the screenshot. What could be the problem? Reboots, system update tried everything, does not help. Thank.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrgmE.png)

Comment: Maybe add the image itself to the question so users don't have to navigate off Stack Overflow. Also, can you be more specific about the error?